# Sending message to chrome extension from a web app

Tags: angular, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am sending some data from my angular web app to the chrome extension. I am using this code:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extensionId,
{
    data: { name: name }
});
```

This code is supposed to send some data to a chrome extension when I log into my angular application. 
This works, but only when, the extension is open at the time of login.

Before clicking on login if I open the extension and click on inspect, and then log into my angular app, the message passing works. However, if I don't open the extension, and click on login and after that if I check the extension, it does not show the related data.

Can anyone tell me as to why is that happening or what am I missing.

Here is how I am catching message passing in chrome extn:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        var email = request.data.name;
        console.log(email);
});
```

This console log works only if I login when the extension is open.

Any suggestions would be welcomed.

Comment: It probably means your listener is added in the wrong place. It should be in your background script (declared via "background" key in manifest.json) and it should be placed in the top scope (not inside an asynchronous function, not inside another event listener, and so on).

Comment: oh damn. I had added it to background.js but at a wrong location. Thanks. @wOxxOm

Answer (score 0):

As sugggested by @wOxxOm, after adding chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener to just the begining of background js, it is now working fine.

Comment: Hi @Praneet Could you share how to have chrome.runtime in angular app? any npm package?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and solve it as below:

1. First, you should send a message from your Angular app

   ```
   parent.postMessage({
       type: type, // a "key" for your data
       data: data
   }, '*');
   ```
2. Now, you can get your message in your extension in the **contentScipt** file

   ```
   parent.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
       if (event.data.type) {
           const type = event.data.type;
           const data = event.data.data;
       }
   });
   ```

Note: **contentScipt** is a javascript file ('*content_extension.js*') that must be created in the **root** of the extension project and must be addressed in the **manifest.json** file like below:

```
"manifest_version": 3,
.
.
.
"content_scripts": [
    {
        js: [
            "content_extension.js", // the file you can get message from Angular app
        ]
    }
],
...
```

It's worth noting that, all of the above instructions were to get the message inside the **contentScript** file. If you want to get a message inside the extension **popup** then you should follow these steps:

1. First, create a popup directory inside the root of your extension project and then create 4 JS, HTML, CSS, and content_popup files inside it as shown below

   ```
   Project
   -- popup
   ---- popup.js
   ---- content_popup.js
   ---- popup.html
   ---- popup.css
   -- content_extension.js
   -- background.js
   -- manifest.js
   ```
2. inside the **content_popup.js** write the following

   ```
   const config = {
       scripts: [
           // add ".js" files to web_accessible_resources in manifest.json
           "popup/popup.js"
       ]
   };

   parent.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
       if (event.data.type) {
           const type = event.data.type;
           const data = event.data.data;
       }
   });

   // prepare and add scripts
   var scriptList = config['scripts'];

   for (var i = 0; i < scriptList.length; i++) {
       var s = document.createElement('script');
       s.src = chrome.runtime.getURL(scriptList[i]);
       s.onload = function () {
           this.remove();
       };
       (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
   }
   ```
3. Add the following code to the end of the **body** tag inside the **popup.html** file

   ```
   <script src="content_popup.js"></script>
   ```
4. Update the **manifest.json** file like below

   ```
   "manifest_version": 3,
   .
   .
   .
   "content_scripts": [
       {
           "js": [
               "content_extension.js"
           ]
       }
   ],
   "action": {
       "default_icon": ...,
       "default_title": ...,
       "default_popup": "popup/popup.html"
   },
   "background": {
       "service_worker": "background.js"
   },
   "web_accessible_resources": [
       {
           "resources": [
               "popup/popup.html",
               "popup/popup.js"
           ]
       }
   ],
   ...
   ```